# Help on installing a tar.gz on Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, compiling, gcc

Okay, I am trying to install, Icecast http://www.icecast.org/

```
guggy@guggy-pc:~/Downloads/icecast$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert i686-pc-linux-gnu file names to i686-pc-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert i686-pc-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... 64
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking alloca.h usability... yes
checking alloca.h presence... yes
checking for alloca.h... yes
checking sys/timeb.h usability... yes
checking sys/timeb.h presence... yes
checking for sys/timeb.h... yes
checking for pwd.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for grp.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... (cached) yes
checking for setuid... yes
checking for chroot... yes
checking for chown... yes
checking for __func__... yes
checking for localtime_r... yes
checking for poll... yes
checking for gettimeofday... yes
checking for ftime... yes
checking for library containing nanosleep... none required
checking sys/socket.h usability... yes
checking sys/socket.h presence... yes
checking for sys/socket.h... yes
checking for socklen_t... yes
checking for va_copy... va_copy
checking sys/select.h usability... yes
checking sys/select.h presence... yes
checking for sys/select.h... yes
checking sys/uio.h usability... yes
checking sys/uio.h presence... yes
checking for sys/uio.h... yes
checking winsock2.h usability... no
checking winsock2.h presence... no
checking for winsock2.h... no
checking for library containing sethostent... none required
checking for library containing getnameinfo... none required
checking for endhostent... yes
checking for getaddrinfo... yes
checking for inet_aton... yes
checking for writev... yes
checking for struct sockaddr_storage.ss_family... yes
checking for inet_pton... yes
checking for xslt-config... no
configure: error: XSLT configuration could not be found
 Readme tells me this 
To build icecast on a Unix platform, perform the following :

Run
   ./configure
   make
   make install
```

> This is the typical procedure if you download the tar file.  If you
>   retrieve the code from subversion or want to rebuild the configure
>   then run `autogen.sh` instead of the configure above. Most people do
>   not need to run `autogen.sh`
>
> A sample config file will be placed in `/usr/local/etc` (on UNIX) or
>   in  the current working directory (on Win32) and is called
>   `icecast.xml`
>
> Documentation for icecast is available in the doc directory, by 
>   viewing `doc/index.html` in a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find the answer here: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/icecast-and-xslt-config-problem-205105/

Basically `sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev`.

As a tip, when you install things like this, always read the README. It is usually in the source directory of the tarball once uncompressed.

Still in building source yourself, when it fails it is usually because it is missing a dependency. Spot the dependency needed, install it with `sudo apt-get install *dependency*` and try build again.

Also, please use some formatting so people can read your post.

Comment: sorry for the huge post it was only way to support my post with more info rather than "I NEED HELP INSTALLING A TTAR.GZ HELP!!"